# How to parse and save large pydantic model to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm writing my first app in `FastAPI` that saves output dictionary output from another program. This output looks something like this. In the header key there is way more data in the tuple `irl` I've just shortened it for question purposes

```
{'worksheet': 'TASKS', 'row_index': 2, 'test_id': '12345', 'test_type': 'onsite', 'execute': 'OFF', 'header': ('ID', 'Execute', 'TaskName', 'Standard'), 'status': 'DONE'}
```

What I first am to create a pydantic model for data serialization

```py
class AdditionalData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    ID: Optional[str] = None
    Execute: Optional[str] = None
    TaskName: Optional[str] = None
    Standard: Optional[str] = None


class MainAction(pydantic.BaseModel):
    worksheet: str
    row_index: int
    test_id: str
    test_type: str
    execute: str
    header: AdditionalData
    status: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class MainActionCreate(pydantic.BaseModel):
      pass
```

Where the problem starts with sqlalchemy models. How should I do them? I've written a model for the `MainAction` as it is the smallest one

```py
class MainActionTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'MainActionTable'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    test_id = sql.Column(sql.String)
    status = sql.Column(sql.String)
    row_index = sql.Column(sql.String)
    test_type = sql.Column(sql.String)
    execute = sql.Column(sql.Boolean, nullable=True)
    worksheet = sql.Column(sql.String)
    date_created = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_updated = sql.Column(sql.DateTime, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
```

but how do I save the header, note that header `irl` has about 20 attributes more

and Currently here is my "save method"

```py
def create_action_point(db: orm.Session, action_create: MainActionCreate):
    action_point = MainActionTable(**action_create.dict())
    db.add(action_point)
    db.commit()
    return action_point

action_tuple = data['action_case']
for x in action_tuple:
    create_action_point(db = db, test_case = TestCasePoint(
       test_id= x.test_id,
       status= x.status,
       row_index= x.row_index,
       test_type= x.test_type,
       execute= x.execute,
       worksheet= x.worksheet
       #header ????
))
```

How to create an appropriate model for my data and how do I save to it

Comment: I don't understand the actual problem. Can you not simply set up a corresponding table for that header data and link it with a foreign key from the action table? Do you not know how to set up a FK in SQLAlchemy or are just unfamiliar with that concept entirely?

Comment: I know the concept but im wondering about other options. Maybe there is a way to generate model from the pydantic one? or different approach

Comment: Are you looking for something like SQLModel? https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/